# Why I can't get my position?

Tags: android, position, latitude-longitude

I'm making an app with android studio and in a welcome popup dialog I want the app gets users's position so I've written the code, but why it can't find my position. WHY?!?I'm trying for days to make it work. Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private TextView addressField; 
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    addressField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView05);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Log.d("SomeTag", provider);
    Log.d("SomeTag", String.valueOf(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)));
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Please wait for location update...");
        longitudeField.setText("Please wait for location update...");
        addressField.setText("Please wait for location update...");
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();

    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        int maxLines = address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();
        for (int i=0; i<maxLines; i++) {
            String addressStr = address.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
            builder.append(addressStr);
            builder.append(" ");
        }

        String fnialAddress = builder.toString(); 

        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
        addressField.setText(fnialAddress); 

    } catch (IOException e) {}
    catch (NullPointerException e) {}
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Can you help me to find what's wrong? 
 Even if it is more simple, I just need the app know the place (I mean the city) where I live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the Android documentation about location strategies [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html). You need to add a listener for location updates. `getLastKnownLocation()` should still work though, but you can not rely on it. Also, are you testing on the emulator? There you often get `null` as a result, if you have not set a location with the dev tools.

Comment: I test the apps on my device

Answer (score 1):

do you write the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

and pls use real phone

or set gps location by ddms for emulator